# AndroidStudio 3.4: "Gradle Project sync failed " Parse Error in Build.Gradle (app)

Tags: gradle

I updated to AndroiStudio 3.4
and now I get Error: "Gradle Project sync failed "

```
ERROR: ParseError at [row,col]:[19,9]
Message: expected start or end tag
Affected Modules: app
```

But I cant find any illegal character or mistake in my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tye.vbassistent"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:0.8.3"  // TyE: Hinzugefügt 2018-04 für 'alert'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The error message does not refer to the `build.gradle` file, but the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Check for syntax errors in the `AndroidManifest.xml` at [row,col]:[19,9]